# Using CURRENT_DATE function on ArcSDE SQL Server Database?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I am writing a script to access data from each day.  I would like to select by attribute and send these features to a local file geodatabase.  After reading some documenation, CURRENT_DATE is the function which reads data for today.

This is an example of my data '2015-02-02 00:00:00'.  I don't have the time for any features, so in reality it is only YYYY-MM-DD.  In a local file geodatabase, the query

PlannedDate = CURRENT_DATE works.  However in my ArcSDE SQL Server connection it does not.

[image]

Comment: Date handling is notoriously different by database provider.  You can't use a file geodatabase construct on a Microsoft database; you must use [a Microsoft equivalent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

Comment: Please always include error messages as text rather than pictures.  That way they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function requires SQL Server Syntax for the mm/dd/yyyy format.

```
PlannedDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Simply replace

```
datetimestart >=CURRENT_DATE -1
```

with

```
datetimestart >=GETDATE()-1
```